# Find rows not increased regularly

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table to store voting and reviewers of product. The reviewers value will increase by time.

```
CREATE TABLE product
(
  product_id character varying(255),
  voting integer,
  reviewers integer,
  created_at timestamp without time zone
);
```

Data

```
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| product_id | reviewers | voting |     created_at      |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
| B000GRMH8A |        50 |      5 | 2015-11-19 00:41:30 |
| B000GRMH8A |        38 |      4 | 2015-11-17 00:42:03 |
| B000GRMH8A |        20 |      2 | 2015-11-15 00:41:23 |
| HXXRSEW    |        50 |      3 | 2015-11-19 00:41:30 |
| HXXRSEW    |        72 |      2 | 2015-11-17 00:42:03 |
| HXXRSEW    |        48 |      1 | 2015-11-15 00:41:23 |
+------------+-----------+--------+---------------------+
```

How can I find all rows that contain invalid data?

[image]

Comment: Why that row is invalid??

Comment: Your Postgres version is missing. And it seems like the row with `('HXXRSEW', 50)` is offending your rule, not `('HXXRSEW', 72)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an error in your question like commented, this could be your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  ( 
   SELECT *, lag(reviewers) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id
                                  ORDER BY created_at) reviewers_prev
   FROM   product
   ) sub
WHERE  reviewers < reviewers_prev;
```

Use the [window function `lag()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) in a subquery, then filter rows where the number of reviewers decreased - offending your rule: `reviewers value will increase by time`.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/dbd62/1)